# Plot coordinates from database onto google maps, keep checking for new values

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, coordinates

I am creating a map application where a device is sending coordinates to a web database every 10 seconds. I've plotted them on google maps. But the problem is I need to reload the map every 5 seconds to load the new coordinates that had come in. For this I can use the setTimeout() javascript function. I am not sure whether I can use this query to poll the last inserted row.. `SELECT lat, lon FROM map ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` ('id' auto increments). I know there might be something better. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. This is my code so far.

```
<?php $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","qwerty");
 mysql_select_db("test", $db); ?>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.386339,-122.085823);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var WalkingPathCoordinates = [];
    <?php  $coordinates="SELECT * FROM map";
            $Result1 = mysql_query($coordinates, $db)or die(mysql_error());  
            while(list($id,$lat,$long) = mysql_fetch_row($Result1))
                { 
                echo "var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(".$lat.",".$long.")\n";
                echo "WalkingPathCoordinates.push(latlng);\n";
                }
    ?> 
var WalkingPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: WalkingPathCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
    });

WalkingPath.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Consider this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625556/using-google-maps-v3-php-and-json-to-plot-markers

Comment: thanks! I just added  setTimeout(initialize,10000); just above WalkingPath.setMap(map); and the page starts refreshing. Is there any way to refresh only the markers and not the whole page?

Comment: whoa! wait a second! Calling initialize fn in Timeout only brings back the page from cache! we should use location.reload(true) instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want the whole map to be refreshed, you can separate your initialize function into two functions. For example, you can have one function called initializeMap() which does the part that displays the map on the page, something like this:

```
var map

function initializeMap() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.386339,-122.085823);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
```

The other function could be called refreshMarkers() and do the stuff related to the markers. With `map` declared outside of the initializeMap() function it is accessable from the refreshMarkers() function.

The initializeMap() function should then only be called once, while the refreshMarker() should be sent to setTimeout() like you did with initialize in your example. In that way, only the refreshMarker() stuff will be done on every timeout.

Unfortunately I have not had the possibility to test this, so I am not sure if you need to also erase the old markers in the refreshMarker function.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: yes! I'm trying this! 'll let u know! I think using ajax would be better!